# Left Shift Overflow

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I don't think I fully understand what's happening in the c compiler when I'm left shifting a signed char.  I'm initializing it with the value 0x8d << 3, and it gives me a warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion.  I'm assuming it's because it's giving too big of a value for a char, however when I do it out by hand I'm getting 104 as an answer.

So does that mean when the value is being shifted it's doing

```
10001101 << 3 = 10001101000
```

and not

```
10001101 << 3 = 01101000
```

Figured it out, but this was the code:

```
signed char testChar = 0x8d << 3;
printf("testChar : %d\n", testChar);
```

Just had to initialize it normally then shift it on another line, super simple stuff.

Comment: The warning is correct, you are creating a compile time constant that overflows a character (8 bit quantity) upon creation.

Comment: @M.M: sorry, I misread.

Comment: Please update your question to show us your actual code. Also, you say you got a warning, but you haven't told us what value is actually stored. I expect it's `104`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is confused: are you initializing a signed char with the value `0x8d << 3`? This is clearly implementation defined as the value is outside the range of the type and the type is signed.  The compiler issues a warning because the loss of precision is explicit.

Conversely, if you mean by *left shifting a signed char*, left shifting a signed char that has a value of `0x8d`, this is again incorrect: unless `char` has more than 8 bits, a signed char cannot have a value of 0x8d.  It can have a value of `-115` that has the same bit pattern.  Left shifting this will be computed this way:

- the `char` value is first promoted to `int`.
- the `int` value is left shifted by 3 but positions: this is equivalent to multiplying by 8.
- if the value is negative, the Standard says the behavior is undefined, but most current processors using 2s complement representation for negative values will just produce the same result as multiplying by 8.

The resulting value is `-920`.  This value does not fit in a `char`.  Storing it to a `char` is implementation defined. The most likely result is a `char` value of `104`.

**EDIT**

You posted the actual code:

```
signed char testChar = 0x8d << 3;
printf("testChar : %d\n", testChar);
```

If `char` is 8 bits, the assignment has implementation defined behavior because `1128` is outside the range of type `signed char` (-128..127), the behavior on most modern processors is to mask off the high order bits and store the 8 low order bits into the destination byte as if it were an `unsigned char`.  In your case, the result is `1128 & 255` -> `104`.

Comment: Ya guess I just have a bad understanding as to when to use bitwise operators.  Just had to initialize the char as 0x8d then on another line shift it, got it printing the correct answer now.

Comment: initializing the `char` to 0x8d is incorrect, the value is outside the range of a signed char.  Left shifting it by any amount is undefined behavior because the value is negative, but for most current processors, the result is the same as multiplying by 8.

Comment: @Lychosand: That didn't solve your problem. It just silenced the compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You haven't shown your actual code</strike> (see below), but you've provided enough information to infer it:

```
signed char c = 0x8d << 3;
```

The constant `0x8d` is of type `int`. Left-shifting it by 3 bits yields the value `0x468`, or equivalently `1128`.

The initialization implicitly converts that value from `int` to `signed char`. Since the value is outside the range of `signed char` (which presumably has a range of `-128` to `+127`, unless you're on a very odd system), the result is implementation-defined.  Typically the high-order bits are discarded, which would yield a result of `0x68`, or `104`.

The compiler is warning you that you're converting the value `1128` to `signed char`, which isn't big enough to hold it.

Perhaps you were expecting `0x8d` to be of type `signed char`? It isn't. The type of an expression is almost always determined by the expression itself, not by the context in which it appears. Integer constants, either decimal, hexadecimal, or octal, are always of type `int`, unless they exceed the value of `INT_MAX`, which is at least `32767` (and probably `2147483647`). (Or unless they have a suffix like `L` or `U`, but that's not relevant here.)

**UPDATE :**

You've shown us your original code:

```
signed char testChar = 0x8d << 3;
printf("testChar : %d\n", testChar);
```

I would expect this to produce a warning, since the value `1128` that you're using to initialize `testChar` causes an overflow. The value stored in `testChar` is implementation-defined, but it's very likely to be `104`, the result of discarding the high-order bits.

If you split the shift into a separate assignment:

```
signed char testChar = 0x8d;
testChar = testChar << 3;
```

then I'd expect the same result. But the value `0x8d` is too big to be stored in a `signed char`, so the conversion yields an implementation-defined result -- most likely `-115`.  And a left-shift on a negative value has undefined behavior -- but again, it will probably yield `-920`, which when converted to `signed char` will probably give you `104`.

Ultimately, the solution to your problem is to do something other than what you're trying to do. The value `0x8d << 3` will not fit into a `signed char`, and any attempt to make it fit is bound to cause problems. By tweaking the code, you might manage to silence the compiler's warnings, but you're still doing things that don't make sense.

Comment: Ya you're on the money, I understand the whole range thing which I find strange how for the question I'm meant to use a signed char.  I'm still giving the char a value of 0x8d and it's compiling and giving me the correct answer, 104 now which is strange.

Comment: See my updated answer. All you've done is hide some information from the compiler, so it's no longer able to warn about the overflow.

Comment: @chqrlie: Nitpick handled.

Comment: Actually, you updated answer is incorrect, promoting the `signed char` to `int` does not yield `141`, but `-115`, which invokes undefined behavior upon left shifting. The compiler no longer complains, but the code now has defined behavior... Who can you trust?

Comment: @KeithThompson: I fixed the backticks, left shift of a **negative** value has undefined behavior, and final conversion yields `104`, not `-104`.

Comment: @chqrlie: Thanks. Some day I'll figure out how to answer questions here.